# How does one create a blockchain snapshot (vs a bootstrap)?

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain, altcoin

I have read [How to create a blockchain snapshot for a hardfork?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/69797/how-to-create-a-blockchain-snapshot-for-a-hardfork) but it does not answer this question.  I understand the bootstrap.dat file is basically a concatenation of the blk000x.dat files, but the snapshot is integrated into a wallet faster.

I am surprised this question is not already asked and answered here as there are several mentions about the use of a snapshot in various answers  to other questions.